# How to Load a file in parallel arrays in java

Tags: java

I have a file that contains 30 lines of data in this format:

> month-day-year-gas price

Here's some sample data:

> May 02, 1994    1.04

Can someone tell me how to load this file in a parallel arrays of months, days, price in java? After this I will have to display the lowest price, and also the highest price, and the average price for each month.

Comment: What is a "parallel array"? And what exactly did you try yourself so far about your homework?

Comment: Are you talking about multi-threading the loading of different sections of the file?  If so, it's almost certainly not worth it.

Comment: You need to clarify your question, especially with respect to _"parallel arrays"_. You also need to demonstrate that you have made some effort to solve your problem, ideally by showing your code. As it stands your question shows no research effort and is likely to be closed.

Comment: as you see guys my question was not that clear bcs i am not trying to get an answer for my homework ,,i am only trying to see how to load data into a parallel arrays ..i know how parallel arrays work but i dont know how to load a data from a file into a parallel arrays

Answer (score 2):

For those who are wondering:

[Parallel Arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array) are arrays where the data in each array is directly related to any given record data row. The index of one array contains related data at the very same index in another array. For example:

```
Dimension[] dim = new Dimension[4];
dim[0] = new Dimension(1,11);
dim[1] = new Dimension(2,22);
dim[2] = new Dimension(3,33);
dim[3] = new Dimension(4,44);

int[] widths = {dim[0].width, dim[1].width, dim[2].width, dim[3].width};
int[] heights = {dim[0].height, dim[1].height, dim[2].height, dim[3].height};

for (int i = 0; i < widths.length; i++) {
    int w = widths[i];
    int h = heights[i];
    System.out.println("Width: " + w + " | Height: " + h);
}
```

And the Console output would be:

```
Width: 1 | Height: 11
Width: 2 | Height: 22
Width: 3 | Height: 33
Width: 4 | Height: 44
```

The ***widths*** and ***heights*** Integer Arrays are considered Parallel Arrays since the data index in each array is directly Related To and Parallel to each other. It doesn't matter which parallel array you iterate through, the current iteration is related to all other parallel arrays.

You can quickly see why it's much better to utilize a Class with Member variables for this sort of thing instead of arrays especially when a multiple number of parallel arrays are involved however, there are some practical uses for it.

> **The task at hand:**

As you read in your file you want to use the [String#split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) method to break that line into the desired chunks you want. The delimiter to use here for the split() method will be a white-space (**" "**) or the [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (RegEx) **"\\s+"**, for example:

```
   "This is my String".split("\\s+");
```

The RegEx argument within the **split()** method basically means, split the string on one or more white-spaces.

In the example below the Parallel Arrays are Class Member variables. The method that fills these Arrays with the pertinent data from file is named **fillParallelArraysWithFileData()** and it accepts one argument, which is the path and name of the data file. Here is the code:

```
private static String[] monthsArray;
private static int[] daysArray;
private static int[] yearsArray;
private static double[] pricesArray;

public static void fillParallelArrayWithFileData(final String filePath) {
    Scanner read = null;
    try {
        read = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
        /* First Read Pass 
           ===============
           Get the number of VALID data lines in file.
           We need this count to know how large to size
           our Parallel Arrays.
        */
        int lineCount = 0;  // counter
        while (read.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = read.nextLine().trim(); // Trim lead/trailing whitespaces (if any)
            /* Skip past blank or comment lines. Lines that start with
               a semicolon (;) or a hash character (#) are considered
               comment lines here and are ignored. You can get rid of 
               those conditions if you like.   */
            if (line.equals("") || line.startsWith(";") || line.startsWith("#")) {
                continue;
            }
            lineCount++;  // Increment the counter.
        }

        /* Second Read Pass 
           ================
           Get the file data and fill Arrays...
           Declare Arrays which will be our parallel arrays.  */
        monthsArray = new String[lineCount];
        daysArray = new int[lineCount];
        yearsArray = new int[lineCount];
        pricesArray = new double[lineCount];
        int indexIncrementer = 0;

        // Start the read from beginning again...
        read = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
        while (read.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = read.nextLine();
            // Remove the comma in data line. Don't want it.
            line = line.trim().replace(",", ""); 
            // If the current line is blank or a comment then skip past it.
            if (line.equals("") || line.startsWith(";") || line.startsWith("#")) {
                continue;
            }
            // Split the current data line
            String[] lineParts = line.split("\\s+");
            monthsArray[indexIncrementer] = lineParts[0];
            daysArray[indexIncrementer] = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[1]);
            yearsArray[indexIncrementer] = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[2]);
            pricesArray[indexIncrementer] = Double.parseDouble(lineParts[3]);
            indexIncrementer++;
        }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND! [" + filePath + "]");
    }
    finally {
        if (read != null) {
            read.close();
        }  
    }
}
```

And an example usage might be:

```
// Fill Arrays with File data.
fillParallelArrayWithFileData("GasPrices.txt");

// Get Gas price for month of July in 1994       
String desiredMonth = "July";
int desiredYear = 1994; 
// We could iterate through any one of the Parallel Arrays
for (int i = 0; i < pricesArray.length; i++) {
    if (monthsArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase(desiredMonth) && yearsArray[i] == desiredYear) {
        String m = "Date: " + monthsArray[i] + " ";
        String d = daysArray[i] + ", ";
        String y = yearsArray[i] + " - ";
        String p = "Gas Price:  $" + pricesArray[i];
        System.out.println(m + d + y + p);
    }
}
```

Output to console window would be something like:

```
Date: July 2, 1994 - Gas Price:  $1.12
```